# MySQL: How to select rows on multiple key/value combinations?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select some data from a SQL database basis on multiple key-value combinations.

I've tried the following, but it did not work.

```
SELECT
*
FROM 
value_to_product
WHERE 
(value_to_product.value_id = 101 AND value_to_product.value_value = 'DVD')
AND
(value_to_product.value_id = 12 AND value_to_product.value_value = 'German')
```

This returned no results, but there is much data which meets both conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

I'll much appreciate every helpful answer.

Comment: Please provide sample data related to your question

Answer (score 1):

The other answers miss the fact that using `OR` means you'll get the rows that match **any** of the criteria, not just the ones that match **all** of them.

The only way I've been able to work this out is to use a `HAVING` clause to eliminate any IDs without the maximum number of matches.

```
SELECT
    id
FROM 
    value_to_product
WHERE 
    (value_to_product.value_id = 101 AND value_to_product.value_value = 'DVD')
  OR
    (value_to_product.value_id = 12 AND value_to_product.value_value = 'German')
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Where `2` should be replaced with the number of total values being checked.

It's also worth noting that in this case there can't be multiple identical `value_id` (key) column values for a given `id`.  Though for most key-value pair tables I would expect this to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `or` instead of `and`

```
SELECT
*
FROM 
value_to_product
WHERE 
(value_to_product.value_id = 101 AND value_to_product.value_value = 'DVD')
OR
(value_to_product.value_id = 12 AND value_to_product.value_value = 'German')
```

Comment: I guess its not OR thing its like the entity should have these key values

Comment: `SELECT
*
FROM 
value_to_product
WHERE value_to_product.value_id IN (12, 101) AND value_to_product.value_value IN ('DVD', 'German')`

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko that Givs other results 101 and german for instance

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid How can the id have value 12 AND 101?

Comment: @Jens According to OP i assume he has some [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) like structure in which each entity can haev many attributes and now he is trying to find the entity with these key pair values

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
*
FROM 
value_to_product
WHERE 
(value_to_product.value_id = 101 AND value_to_product.value_value = 'DVD')
OR /* not AND */
(value_to_product.value_id = 12 AND value_to_product.value_value = 'German')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's why you're not getting any results:
Your WHERE clause is asking for all records that have a value_id of 101 **AND** a value_id of 12. There's obviously not a single record that has two different values :)

Maybe your WHERE clause should be:

```
WHERE 
(value_to_product.value_id = 101 AND value_to_product.value_value = 'DVD')
**OR**
(value_to_product.value_id = 12 AND value_to_product.value_value = 'German')
```

It would help to know the structure of your table, and maybe I could give you more insight as to the specific problem you're trying to solve.

(übrigens, bin auch deutschsprachig bei Bedarf)

Comment: Now I understand it - like we say in german: wie Schuppen von den Augen.

Then i think the structure of the table is will not support what i´m trying to do.

It´s:
    value_to_product_id bigint(9) Auto-Inkrement  
    products_id mediumint(6)   
    value_id mediumint(6)  
    value_value varchar(1024)

Comment: Haha, schön dass die Schuppen fliegen :D I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish with your query - can you clarify that? I'm sure there's a good solution.